# Is there a data format lighter than json?

Tags: json, mobile, format, dataset

We have data with fixed keys in json, like

```
   { a:1,b:1,c:1},{ a:2,b:2,c:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3}......
```

Is there any format lighter than json, like

```
           {a,b,c},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}.......
```

I don't want to post keys for each dataset. Size of data is so important for me for mobile...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure you can build one if necessary, but is it really? What are you trying to build, on what kinds of platforms? What kind of data are you sending?

Comment: Maybe Google Protocol Buffers.

Comment: we are sending json data string but very large volume, every key as a char eats battery. we are working on TCP protocol , data is generated in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using json:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "C"
    ],
    "values": [
        [
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            2,
            2,
            2
        ],
        [
            3,
            3,
            3
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Then I think you mean, is there any "Standard" format like that.
Unfortunately, as of now there doesn't exist any such format, you may use properties/ db queries etc, or modified json just like above or create a standard of your own. 

It is an interesting question, please do let us know what did you finalized upon.

Answer (score 0):

http://msgpack.org/ or https://github.com/google/protobuf or just CSV if you don't repeat your header a lot (or even don't send it)